# Cucumber+TestNG+Cucable plugin: How can I pass the appium driver instance that I create in the @beforemethod instance to the page objects?

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumberjs, cucumber-junit

Here is what I am trying to build:

1. Cucumber based tests with TestNG Executor
2. TestNG Executor so that I can re-run failed tests
3. Cucable plugin - so that the scenarios are split into individual files and runner is auto generated during run time for each of the scenarios. (Enables parallel execution)

Below is the test runner:

```
@CucumberOptions(
        glue = "com.fifa.stepdefs",
        features = {"target/parallel/features/[CUCABLE:FEATURE].feature"},
        plugin = {"json:target/cucumber-report/[CUCABLE:RUNNER].json"}
)

public class CucableJavaTemplate implements IRetryAnalyzer {

    private int count = 0;
    private static int maxTry = 3;

    @Override
    public boolean retry(ITestResult iTestResult) {
        if (!iTestResult.isSuccess()) {  ;//Check if test not succeed
            if (count < maxTry) {                            //Check if maxtry count is reached
                count++;                                    //Increase the maxTry count by 1
                iTestResult.setStatus(ITestResult.FAILURE);  //Mark test as failed
                return true;                                 //Tells TestNG to re-run the test
            } else {
                iTestResult.setStatus(ITestResult.FAILURE);  //If maxCount reached,test marked as failed
            }
        } else {
            iTestResult.setStatus(ITestResult.SUCCESS);      //If test passes, TestNG marks it as passed
        }
        return false;
    }
    private TestNGCucumberRunner testNGCucumberRunner;

    @BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUpClass() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Before Scenario ****");
        testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
    }

    @Test(groups = "cucumber", description = "Runs Cucumber Scenarios", dataProvider = "scenarios",retryAnalyzer = CucableJavaTemplate.class)
    public void scenario(PickleEventWrapper pickleEvent, CucumberFeatureWrapper cucumberFeature) throws Throwable {
        testNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(pickleEvent.getPickleEvent());
    }

    @DataProvider
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return testNGCucumberRunner.provideScenarios();
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("After Scenario ****");
        testNGCucumberRunner.finish();
    }
}
```

If I create a Driver instance in the before class: How can I pass it to page object files or step def files?

Comment: U can look at using a DI tool. Try the cucumber pico-container implementation. Look at [this](http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2017/04/01/sharing-state-between-steps-in-cucumberjvm-using-picocontainer). BTW u can use the inbuilt rerun plugin and parallel execution if u are using version greater than 4.

Answer (score 0):

I gave similar answer on this question:
[How to match a specific java file with specific feature file in cucumber](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56744786/how-to-match-a-specific-java-file-with-specific-feature-file-in-cucumber/56767009#56767009)
If you have annotated the driver class with @ScenarioScoped then you can easily use Guice to inject this instance in your other classes.